Is a translated vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the same vector?
I am rather confused if translating a vector "changes" the vector in any way. Based on what I have been told, and the basic definition of a vector as a quantity with magnitude and direction, a vector should have no notion of an origin attached to it. If this is the case, however, a translated vector space (affine space) should always remain the same, regardless of the translation. But this seems not to be the case. Essentially, I am asking if specifying the origin of a vector is necessary to define it?

It is better to think of vectors as translations of the space. A (free) vector does not have a point of application. Each "arrow" represents the action of your vector on the application point (the vector translates the point of application to its "tip".
A vector space is thus the group of translations of the associated affine space. If you fix a point in your affine space, you can identify it with the associated vector space, by relating each point to the vector needed to translate the origin to the given point.
In Physics, however, there are other concepts of vector, where the point of application (or the line of application) matter. Thus a force is not a free vector, since the line of application matters, giving different torques, etc. There are also axial vectors.
But again, vectors studied in Linear Algebra are free vectors.

Would the origin vector ($\vec{0}$) be a free vector?

The null vector is a free vector.
